# Identify characters for each row and return them in a column

Tags: r, character

I'm working on a huge dataset in R studio and would want to identify the characters for each row (except missing "NN") then return a new column with those characters for each row.

I write this table as an example:

```
TC1 | TC73| TC88| TC9| TC17| TC25
NN  |  GG |  GG |  CC|  GG |  CC
TT  |  CC |  NN |  TT|  TT |  CC
AA  |  CC |  CC |  AA|  NN |  NN
```

I would like to obtain the following output:

```
alleles | TC1 | TC73| TC88| TC9| TC17| TC25
G/C   | NN  |  GG |  GG |  CC|  GG |  CC
T/C   | TT  |  CC |  NN |  TT|  TT |  CC
A/C   | AA  |  CC |  CC |  AA|  NN |  NN
```

Comment: Does order matter of the `alleles`?

Comment: `apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(setdiff(x, "NN"), collapse = "/"))`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It might be helpful to see your code to know how you want to approach this

Comment: To expand on @r2evans answer: `cbind(alleles = apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(setdiff(x, "NN"), collapse = "/")), df)`

Comment: @akash87 Thank you both, I edited my question. Actually the desired output for the column alleles would be G/C, T/C, A/C instead of GG/CC...